# How to display this imported data not in the form of a table but in the form of strings in Jupyter?

Tags: python, pandas, popup, jupyter

The data(Malibu Beach,Commerce and Long Beach) was loaded for pop-ups from Excel.I used this code below and it displayed in the form of table when I open any pop-up (picture 1). I would like to make it over in the form of springs( Example: picture 2). Can you prompt me how to do this?

```
import folium
import pandas as pd
import io

data = '''
Name A1 A2 A3 LAT LON
"Malibu Beach" 0.63 0.55 0.95 34.03194 -118.698387
'Commerce' 0.17 0.45 0.25 34.00031 -118.159770
"Long Beach" 0.19 0.21 0.09 33.77171 -118.181310'''

data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

map = folium.Map([data.LAT.mean(),
data.LON.mean()],zoom_control=True,zoom_start = 9,scrollWheelZoom=True,tiles = "Stamen Terrain")

for i in range(len(data)):
html = data.loc[i,['Name','A1','A2','A3']].to_frame().T.to_html(
  classes="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-responsive")
popup = folium.Popup(html, max_width=500)
folium.Marker([data.iloc[i]['LAT'], data.iloc[i]['LON']],popup =folium.Popup(html, max_width=500),icon=folium.Icon(icon='cloud',color='darkblue')).add_to(map)

map
```

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt5an.png)

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0r5b.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't transpose your data with `.T`:

```
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

map = folium.Map([data.LAT.mean(),
data.LON.mean()],zoom_control=True,zoom_start = 9,scrollWheelZoom=True,tiles = "Stamen Terrain")

for i in range(len(data)):
   html = data.loc[i,['Name','A1','A2','A3']].to_frame().to_html(header=False, classes="table table-condensed table-responsive", border=0)
   popup = folium.Popup(html, max_width=500)
   folium.Marker([data.iloc[i]['LAT'], data.iloc[i]['LON']],popup =folium.Popup(html, max_width=500),icon=folium.Icon(icon='cloud',color='darkblue')).add_to(map)

map
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for explanation but maybe I can use another method? And you know in which types can display any data except table?

Comment: Do you want to use `popup` or `tooltips`?

Comment: Tooltips more preferable